# Seemingly contradictory host lookup results. (NXDOMAIN) and IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system

If I execute:

```
$ host rocky-k3.sst.example.com
```

I get this output:

```
rocky-k3.sst.example.com has address 10.0.3.53
rocky-k3.sst.example.com has address 10.0.3.51
rocky-k3.sst.example.com has address 10.0.3.52
Host rocky-k3.sst.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Why am I getting that `NXDOMAIN` line of output?

Comment: `host` by default looks up and displays A=IPv4 AAAA=IPv6 and MX records (in that order); whatever nameserver you are using is apparently defectively returning NXDOMAIN for one of the latter when it should return an empty answer section. `nslookup` similarly by default does A and AAAA (but not MX), and also displays the nameserver used; you might see if that is more helpful. PS: the word you wanted is 'seemingly'; 'seemly' means 'in good taste, proper, appropriate, polite'

Comment: `host` , and `nslookup` are NOT good DNS troubleshooting tools. Only  `dig` or similar is (doing one query, getting one answer). If you don't disclose real names noone can help you in any meaningful way, so you can just try yourself online with a DNS troubleshooting tool like DNSViz.